# How can I enable on row click and redirect to a new tab with the following data of that selected row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I'm using mui-datatable and how can I redirect the user to another page by clicking on a row and the data of that row will also be passed onto that page?

This is the error I'm getting:

```
DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': Symbol(react.element) could not be cloned.

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { array: []};
  }

  columns = [
    "Order ID",
    "Name",
  ];
  options = {
    filter: true,
     onRowClick: (data) => this.props.history.push("/details", data),
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
    //fetching data from the firestore
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  render() {
    
    return  (
      <div>
        <MUIDataTable
          title={"Pending Orders"}
          columns={this.columns}
          data={this.state.orders}
          options={this.options}
        />
```

Comment: You can try using browsers `localStorage to temporarily save row data & then clear it out on component unmount.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#example

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the user with the row Data using **useHistory** hook. history.push accepts path and state (data that user wants to pass to the new route) as an argument.

```
/*** BasicTable.js Line number 35 in the sandbox link***/

const history = useHistory();
// rowData is the data of the clicked row.
const handleRowClick = (rowData) => {
   history.push("/nextpage", rowData);
};
```

For extracting the state you can use useLocation hook.

```
 const location = useLocation();
 const rowData = location.state;
```

[Sandbox Url](https://codesandbox.io/s/67543065-to4bp)

Comment: I've updated my codes and there's an error I'm getting, "DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': Symbol(react.element) could not be cloned."

Comment: Can you share the code of **MUIDataTable**? Where you have called the option function.

Comment: I've edited my post. The option function is before the render

Comment: I found that. But I was talking about the code snipped where you had written onClick function inside MUIDataTable for row.

Comment: Jus this "onRowClick: (data) => this.props.history.push("/details", data)"

Comment: I can go to the next page if I'll code it like this where data is in a string. "onRowClick: (data) => this.props.history.push("/details", "data")" but only the string "data" will be displayed in the next page

Comment: I just wanna ensure that you are passing row data in the onRowClick function and not the event object(if you don't pass explicitly it will pass event object only). 
Like I have done in 56th line of BasicTable.js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232476/discussion-between-priyansh-gaharana-and-jen-jennie).